# is it possible to have loop referenced functions

Tags: lua

currently I am trying to do something like

```
function a()
    b()
end

function b()
    a()
end
```

and lua is not liking it since function b is not defined when I am defining function a. Is there a way to make it work?

Edited:
I am writing an addon for "Elder scrolls Online" and they seem to have their own implementation of lua. I am getting function is nil error for calling b inside function a.

Comment: This code works in Lua. Can you show a full example that you can run with Lua and does not work as you expect?

Comment: Works fine for me!  Your particular example will end up behaving like an endless goto from A to B to A ... due to tail calls being optimized into GOTOs.  Your actual routines will possibly be more involved and not end with a call to the other function, so the only requirement would be to have a terminating condition somewhere to avoid running out of stack space.

Comment: @catwell um...I guess it has something to do with the game's implementation... cuz with the exact same setup I am getting Error "function expected instead of nil"

Comment: @tonypdmtr sorry that I didn't be specific. It is an addon I am trying to write for a game called Elder scrolls online, the addon language is lua but I guess its not using the native lua implementation since I am getting nil error for function b inside a. I am aware of the infinite loop and the condition was removed for simplicity.

Comment: The game's implementation, what is the value of `_VERSION`?

Comment: @KeithThompson 2013.1.0 r13331

Comment: That's peculiar. With straight Lua, I get `"Lua 5.2"` or `"Lua 5.3"`. It does look like they're using a different implementation. I wonder why. (To be clear, is `"2013.1.0 r13331"` the value of the Lua variable `_VERSION`?)

Comment: @KeithThompson yea, that's what I get for printing _VERSION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the variables prior to function definition:

```
local a, b
a = function()
    b()
end

b = function()
    a()
end
```

Comment: @Steve: But *why* does it work? The code in your question works correctly, and the `local` declarations shouldn't be necessary. Have you tried running your original code directly, as `lua script.lua` or with a `#!` line? Is there more to the code that's failing?

Comment: @KeithThompson I am writing an addon for "Elder scrolls Online" I guess it has something to do with their lua implementation. I do not have anymore info other than the error window which says the function is nil.

Comment: @Steve: Then there's more context than what you've shown us in the question. Since you've accepted an answer, either hjpotter92 is familiar with the context or it was a lucky guess. But your question would be more useful to future readers with more explanation.

Comment: @KeithThompson question updated to reflect the situation. thanks for pointing it out